# Michael Hartl's rails tutorial: reusing sessions resource for multiple User types

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby on Rails through Micheal Hartl's [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org).

In my web application, I require two types of Users, called publishers and subscribers. Currently I have a publishers resource and a subscribers resource. I'd like both of them to be able to use the sessions resource for signin/signout.

I'm looking for some direction on how to implement this. Should my publisher and subscriber resource inherit from the User resource, so that, for example, the following code works through polymorphism?

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
  else
    # Create an error message and re-render the signin form.
  end
end
```

The publisher and subscriber do not have many common fields and different capabilities, so I think they should be modeled as two separate resources, but how to have them share the Sessions resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to make the **User** class be used only for login and the user would belong to a Publisher or Subscriber via a polymorphic association, as in:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :identifiable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

If you don't know what polymorphic associations are, [you should read this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

This code would be used like this:

```
subscriber = Subscriber.find(1)
user = User.new
user.identifiable = subscriber
user.save
```

So, your **Subscriber** or **Publisher** is going to be related to one user, the :identifiable field is a relationship (a polymorphic relationship) to another object.

With this a user could use this identifiable association to be a **Subscriber** or a **Publisher** and your **SessionsController** would be reused for both of them (and all the authentication logic too, since it would live inside of **User** and not these other classes).

Comment: Thanks. These are likely very novice followup questions, please bear with me. (1) What does it mean to be "identifiable"? Is `:identifiable` a keyword in Rails (wasn't able to find any documentation on it). (2) Upon having logged in as a User, how would I "handoff" to the appropriate Publisher or Subscriber controller?

Comment: Would this be the proper association in the Publisher and Subscriber declaration? `belongs_to :user, :as => :identifiable`

Comment: Exactly. This way you reuse the user model for both.